# Get path or url of selected image jquery bxslider

Tags: jquery, bxslider

I'm using http://bxslider.com/ for my photo gallery.

I need to get the path or the url of the image that is currently selected to pass to another variable.

**How can I get the path or URL of the image that is currently selected?. That is, how I can get the image that the user is viewing?**

Thank you very much!! :D

Comment: Read about the different callbacks in their options API http://bxslider.com/options

Comment: Thank you I see getCurrentSlide(). Can you paste a example? Thank you!

Comment: That just gets the index. You could do `onNextSlide()` and use the provided `currentSlideHtmlObject` which will give you the DOM element.

Comment: Thank you @elclanrs, Please Can you write a response with this code for I can accept your response and give you Karma. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't tried this but it should work in `onBeforeSlide()` or `onAfterSlide()` depending on what you want to accomplish.

```
function(idx, total, obj){

    // You can do this
    var src = $(obj).attr('src'); // Not sure if object already wrapped in jQuery

    // Or this
    var src = $('#slider img').eq(idx).attr('src');

    // Rest of the code...

}
```